# RSA cipher incompatibility - python script cannot decrypt a key encrypted by a bash script

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, rsa, pycrypto

I have written a python script that implements encryption and decryption. To send a key for the encrypted data to the receiver the program uses RSA public key encryption and decryption on a randomly generated key.

Below is the encryption and decryption methods in the python script I have used to encrypt and decrypt a key with public/private keys:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

def encrypt_public_key(msg, public_key):
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)
    return cipher.encrypt(msg)

def decrypt_private_key(msg, private_key):
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    return cipher.decrypt(msg)
```

My program should communicate with a classmates program, however, this person has written his program as a bash script using the following command to encrypt and decrypt:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey id_rsa.pub.pem -pubin -in key.bin -out key.bin.enc
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey id_rsa.pem -in key.bin.enc -out key.bin
```

When my program tries to decrypt my classmates encrypted key I get this error:

```
File "[script-path]", line 54, in decrypt_private_key
return cipher.decrypt(msg)
File "C:\[path_to_python]\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 167, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Ciphertext with incorrect length.")
ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.
```

I believe that this means that our scripts does not use the same cipher, am I correct with this assumtion? However, I cannot find which cipher is used for the bash script (and my classmate does not know either) and I am struggling to find how I can use another cipher with the python Crypto module.

I have tried to switch my encryption and decryption methods to something similar to this:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

def encrypt_public_key(msg, public_key):
    return public_key.encrypt(msg, 32)
def decrypt_private_key(msg, private_key):
    return private_key.decrypt(msg)
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
File "[script_path]", line 52, in decrypt_private_key
    return private_key.decrypt(msg)
  File "[python-path]\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 378, in decrypt
    raise NotImplementedError("Use module Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP instead")
NotImplementedError: Use module Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP instead
```

Which is the cipher (PKCS1_OAEP) that is not working with the encrypted key from my classmate.

Do you have any suggestions on what I can do to solve this? Is the problem that we are using different ciphers and is there a way to switch my cipher or do I have to switch from my python Crypto module?

Comment: Don't use PyCrypto. Use cryptography. PyCrypto hasn't been updated in 6 years. Not the solution to your problem, just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using different RSA padding schemes. 
Maybe your classmate could try using the `rsautl` OAEP padding option `-oaep`.

It seems the default padding mode for openssl `rsautl` is `-pkcs` (PKCS#1 v1.5).

So alternatively, you could try using:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
```

Comment: I have switched my OAEP to PKCS1_v1_5 now following this guide: [link](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/pkcs1_v1_5.html). But I get the error `AttributeError: 'PKCS115_SigScheme' object has no attribute 'decrypt'` when trying to decrypt with `cipher.decrypt(msg, sentinel)`. I have looked at the source code of PKCS1_v1_5 and it has the decrypt method. Do you know why this is happening?